# Selecting child elements of a specific parent

Tags: jquery, parent, css-selectors

I have an example of code (written by someone else) that works, but I cannot find any reference to this specific syntax to explain why it works:

```
var parent = $("#theParentDiv");
var child = $(".title", parent);
```

This will give me the child of the parent (there is only one), and excludes all other .title elements that do not descend from this parent.

How/why does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference is [here, in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). The second parameter is called "context" by the docs.

It works because jQuery converts the call into a call to [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find).

This:

```
var child = $(".title", parent);
```

becomes this:

```
var child = $(parent).find(".title");
```

...which only looks for elements that match the selector if they're descendants of the parent.

In the 1.10.2 un-minified jQuery script, this happens on line 202, which looks like this:

```
return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
```